# Python - pickling fails for numpy.void objects

Tags: python, serialization, numpy, marshalling, pickle

```
    >>> idmapfile = open("idmap", mode="w")
    >>> pickle.dump(idMap, idmapfile)
    >>> idmapfile.close()
    >>> idmapfile = open("idmap")
    >>> unpickled = pickle.load(idmapfile)
    >>> unpickled == idMap
False
idMap[1]
{1537: (552, 1, 1537, 17.793827056884766, 3), 1540: (4220, 1, 1540, 19.31205940246582, 3), 1544: (592, 1, 1544, 18.129131317138672, 3), 1675: (529, 1, 1675, 18.347782135009766, 3), 1550: (4048, 1, 1550, 19.31205940246582, 3), 1424: (1528, 1, 1424, 19.744396209716797, 3), 1681: (1265, 1, 1681, 19.596025466918945, 3), 1560: (3457, 1, 1560, 20.530569076538086, 3), 1690: (477, 1, 1690, 17.395542144775391, 3), 1691: (554, 1, 1691, 13.446117401123047, 3), 1436: (3010, 1, 1436, 19.596025466918945, 3), 1434: (3183, 1, 1434, 19.744396209716797, 3), 1441: (3570, 1, 1441, 20.589576721191406, 3), 1435: (476, 1, 1435, 19.640911102294922, 3), 1444: (527, 1, 1444, 17.98480224609375, 3), 1478: (1897, 1, 1478, 19.596025466918945, 3), 1575: (614, 1, 1575, 19.371648788452148, 3), 1586: (2189, 1, 1586, 19.31205940246582, 3), 1716: (3470, 1, 1716, 19.158674240112305, 3), 1590: (2278, 1, 1590, 19.596025466918945, 3), 1463: (991, 1, 1463, 19.31205940246582, 3), 1594: (1890, 1, 1594, 19.596025466918945, 3), 1467: (1087, 1, 1467, 19.31205940246582, 3), 1596: (3759, 1, 1596, 19.744396209716797, 3), 1602: (3011, 1, 1602, 20.530569076538086, 3), 1547: (490, 1, 1547, 17.994071960449219, 3), 1605: (658, 1, 1605, 19.31205940246582, 3), 1606: (1794, 1, 1606, 16.964881896972656, 3), 1719: (1826, 1, 1719, 19.596025466918945, 3), 1617: (583, 1, 1617, 11.894925117492676, 3), 1492: (3441, 1, 1492, 20.500667572021484, 3), 1622: (3215, 1, 1622, 19.31205940246582, 3), 1628: (2761, 1, 1628, 19.744396209716797, 3), 1502: (1563, 1, 1502, 19.596025466918945, 3), 1632: (1108, 1, 1632, 15.457141876220703, 3), 1468: (3779, 1, 1468, 19.596025466918945, 3), 1642: (3970, 1, 1642, 19.744396209716797, 3), 1518: (612, 1, 1518, 18.570245742797852, 3), 1647: (854, 1, 1647, 16.964881896972656, 3), 1650: (2099, 1, 1650, 20.439058303833008, 3), 1651: (540, 1, 1651, 18.552841186523438, 3), 1653: (613, 1, 1653, 19.237197875976563, 3), 1532: (537, 1, 1532, 18.885730743408203, 3)}

>>> unpickled[1]
{1537: (64880, 1638, 56700, -1.0808743559293829e+18, 152), 1540: (64904, 1638, 0, 0.0, 0), 1544: (54472, 1490, 0, 0.0, 0), 1675: (6464, 1509, 0, 0.0, 0), 1550: (43592, 1510, 0, 0.0, 0), 1424: (43616, 1510, 0, 0.0, 0), 1681: (0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0), 1560: (400, 152, 400, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1690: (408, 152, 408, 2.7201111331839077e+26, 34), 1435: (424, 152, 61512, 1.0122952080313192e-39, 0), 1436: (400, 152, 400, 20.250289916992188, 3), 1434: (424, 152, 62080, 1.0122952080313192e-39, 0), 1441: (400, 152, 400, 12.250144958496094, 3), 1691: (424, 152, 42608, 15.813941955566406, 3), 1444: (400, 152, 400, 19.625289916992187, 3), 1606: (424, 152, 42432, 5.2947192852601414e-22, 41), 1575: (400, 152, 400, 6.2537390010262572e-36, 0), 1586: (424, 152, 42488, 1.0122601755697111e-39, 0), 1716: (400, 152, 400, 6.2537390010262572e-36, 0), 1590: (424, 152, 64144, 1.0126357235581501e-39, 0), 1463: (400, 152, 400, 6.2537390010262572e-36, 0), 1594: (424, 152, 32672, 17.002994537353516, 3), 1467: (400, 152, 400, 19.750289916992187, 3), 1596: (424, 152, 7176, 1.0124003054161436e-39, 0), 1602: (400, 152, 400, 18.500289916992188, 3), 1547: (424, 152, 7000, 1.0124003054161436e-39, 0), 1605: (400, 152, 400, 20.500289916992188, 3), 1478: (424, 152, 42256, -6.0222748507426518e+30, 222), 1719: (400, 152, 400, 6.2537390010262572e-36, 0), 1617: (424, 152, 16472, 1.0124283313854301e-39, 0), 1492: (400, 152, 400, 6.2537390010262572e-36, 0), 1622: (424, 152, 35304, 1.0123190301052127e-39, 0), 1628: (400, 152, 400, 6.2537390010262572e-36, 0), 1502: (424, 152, 63152, 19.627988815307617, 3), 1632: (400, 152, 400, 19.375289916992188, 3), 1468: (424, 152, 38088, 1.0124213248931084e-39, 0), 1642: (400, 152, 400, 6.2537390010262572e-36, 0), 1518: (424, 152, 63896, 1.0127436235399031e-39, 0), 1647: (400, 152, 400, 6.2537390010262572e-36, 0), 1650: (424, 152, 53424, 16.752857208251953, 3), 1651: (400, 152, 400, 19.250289916992188, 3), 1653: (424, 152, 50624, 1.0126497365427934e-39, 0), 1532: (400, 152, 400, 6.2537390010262572e-36, 0)}
```

The keys come out fine, the values are screwed up.  I tried same thing loading file in binary mode; didn't fix the problem.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

Edit:
Here's the code with binary.  Note that the values are different in the unpickled object.

```
>>> idmapfile = open("idmap", mode="wb")
>>> pickle.dump(idMap, idmapfile)
>>> idmapfile.close()
>>> idmapfile = open("idmap", mode="rb")
>>> unpickled = pickle.load(idmapfile)
>>> unpickled==idMap
False
>>> unpickled[1]
{1537: (12176, 2281, 56700, -1.0808743559293829e+18, 152), 1540: (0, 0, 15934, 2.7457842047810522e+26, 108), 1544: (400, 152, 400, 4.9518498821046956e+27, 53), 1675: (408, 152, 408, 2.7201111331839077e+26, 34), 1550: (456, 152, 456, -1.1349175514578289e+18, 152), 1424: (432, 152, 432, 4.5939047815653343e-40, 11), 1681: (408, 152, 408, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1560: (376, 152, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1690: (376, 152, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1435: (376, 152, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1436: (376, 152, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1434: (376, 152, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1441: (376, 152, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1691: (376, 152, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1444: (376, 152, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1606: (25784, 2281, 376, -3.2883343074537754e+26, 34), 1575: (24240, 2281, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1586: (24240, 2281, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1716: (24240, 2281, 376, -3.0093091599657311e-35, 26), 1590: (24240, 2281, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1463: (24240, 2281, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1594: (24240, 2281, 376, -4123208450048.0, 196), 1467: (25784, 2281, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1596: (25784, 2281, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1602: (25784, 2281, 376, -5.9963281433905448e+26, 76), 1547: (25784, 2281, 376, -218106240.0, 139), 1605: (25784, 2281, 376, -3.7138649803377281e+27, 56), 1478: (376, 152, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1719: (25784, 2281, 376, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1617: (25784, 2281, 376, -1.4411779941597184e+17, 237), 1492: (25784, 2281, 376, 2.8596493694487798e-30, 80), 1622: (25784, 2281, 376, 184686084096.0, 93), 1628: (1336, 152, 1336, 3.1691839245470052e+29, 179), 1502: (1272, 152, 1272, -5.2042207205116645e-17, 99), 1632: (1208, 152, 1208, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1468: (1144, 152, 1144, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1642: (1080, 152, 1080, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1518: (1016, 152, 1016, 4.0240902787680023e+35, 145), 1647: (952, 152, 952, -985172619034624.0, 237), 1650: (888, 152, 888, 12094787289088.0, 66), 1651: (824, 152, 824, 2.1299736657737219e-43, 0), 1653: (760, 152, 760, 0.00018310768064111471, 238), 1532: (696, 152, 696, 8.8978061885676389e+26, 125)}
```

---

OK I've isolated the problem, but don't know why it's so.  First, apparently what I'm pickling are not tuples (though they look like it), but instead numpy.void types.  Here is a series to illustrate the problem.

```
first = run0.detections[0]
>>> first
(1, 19, 1578, 82.637763977050781, 1)
>>> type(first)
<type 'numpy.void'>
>>> firstTuple = tuple(first)
>>> theFile = open("pickleTest", "w")
>>> pickle.dump(first, theFile)
>>> theTupleFile = open("pickleTupleTest", "w")
>>> pickle.dump(firstTuple, theTupleFile)
>>> theFile.close()
>>> theTupleFile.close()
>>> first
(1, 19, 1578, 82.637763977050781, 1)
>>> firstTuple
(1, 19, 1578, 82.637764, 1)
>>> theFile = open("pickleTest", "r")
>>> theTupleFile = open("pickleTupleTest", "r")
>>> unpickledTuple = pickle.load(theTupleFile)
>>> unpickledVoid = pickle.load(theFile)
>>> type(unpickledVoid)
<type 'numpy.void'>
>>> type(unpickledTuple)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> unpickledTuple
(1, 19, 1578, 82.637764, 1)
>>> unpickledTuple == firstTuple
True
>>> unpickledVoid == first
False
>>> unpickledVoid
(7936, 1705, 56700, -1.0808743559293829e+18, 152)
>>> first
(1, 19, 1578, 82.637763977050781, 1)
```

Comment: show us the same code with binary-mode writing and reading.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code.  I tried it out and it worked just fine.  I wasn't sure exactly what you were pickling however, I used an array of dicts because that looked similar.

Comment: Works for me in Python 2.4.5, 2.5.2, and with the obvious changes in Python 3.0.  Please post actual test data for which it fails.

Also, what version of pickle are you using?  pickle, or cPickle?

Comment: idMap is a list of dictionaries, where dictionary is int-> tuple object.  idMap[1] is available at http://pastebin.com/f44a58355

I'm using pickle, not cPickle.  I'm using Python 2.6.4 on WindowsXP (r264:75708, Oct 26 2009, 08:23:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: In my response below, I used your data, with pickle (not cPickle) on both python2.51 (Cygwin) and python3.1 (Windows) using all protocols and it works

Comment: so, pickling will only work with top level module functions and classes, and will not pickle class data, so if some numpy class code/data are required to produce a representation of the numpy void type pickling isn't going to work as expected. It may be that the numpy package has implemented an internal __repr__ to print the void  type as a tuple, if this is the case then what you pickled certainly is not going to be what you printed.

Comment: jottos - if you submit that comment as an answer, I'll accept it and close the question.

That must be what's happening internally.  I'm just wrapping it in a tuple call and the pickling works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so, pickling will only work with top level module functions and classes, and will not pickle class data, so if some numpy class code/data are required to produce a representation of the numpy void type pickling isn't going to work as expected. It may be that the numpy package has implemented an internal repr to print the void type as a tuple, if this is the case then what you pickled certainly is not going to be what you printed. – [jottos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14555/jottos) Dec 29 '09 at 18:42

Answer (score 1):

I agree. I think there is a problem with serializing numpy.void

example that doesn't work (Python 2.7.3, numpy 1.6.1):

```
import pickle, numpy as np
my_array = np.array([('hello', 45.5, 'world')], dtype=[('a', str, 10), ('b', float), ('c', str,10)])
my_void = my_array[0]
print my_void
print pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(my_void))
```

which will print:

```
('hello', 45.5, 'world')
('\xc0\x00llo', 45.5, 'world')
```

The first looks like a `tuple`, but it is actually a `numpy.void`

So to avoid this you can't have `numpy.void`, you should instead wrap your void with `numpy.array()` or call `.tolist()` on your `numpy.void`.

Edit: There is a bug in numpy https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3188

Answer (score 0):

Something with your system (filesystem?) ; I would try pickling in binary mode; use `dump(idMap, idmapfile, protocol=2)`

Comment: Did not fix the problem - same result.

Answer (score 0):

So, using python31 I made just a small change to your example and it worked fine. Note that I added the "b" for binary in the file open's I tried this with all protocols and it worked for each

```
idmapfile = open("idmap", mode="wb")
pickle.dump(idMap, idmapfile)
idmapfile.close()
idmapfile = open("idmap", "rb")
unpickled = pickle.load(idmapfile)
print ('they are equal', unpickled == idMap)


src> ./pick.py
they are equal True
```