# Pickle still fails for numpy.void objects

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, pickle

Over a year ago I [reported a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue39423) I encountered while pickling some fairly complex data. At the time I didn't know what the issue was and believed it might have had something todo with recursive referencing.

I've encountered the issue several times while working on my project, but only did arbitrary things trying to fix it until the error disappeared. Now I finally took the time to home in on the source of the issue and refine my MWE. This is what I came up with:

```py
import pickle
import numpy as np


# create data
dtypes = [('f0', 'O')]
# for some reason, I need at least an extra of 19 fields for it to crash
# immediately
dtypes += [(f'f{i+1}', 'i4') for i in range(19)]
data = np.empty(1, dtype=dtypes)
# print(data[0])

# dump data
dump = pickle.dumps(data[0], pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
# print('dumping works')

# load data
load = pickle.loads(dump)
# print('loading works')

# process crashes here if len(dtypes) > 19
print(load)

# process prints random data, e.g.

# (((...), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0,
# -1931060898, 32763, 1472326776, 503, 1482667496, 503, 0, 0, 1484270024,
# 503, 1472326776, 503, -1930803631, 32763, 1484270024, 503)

# or

# ((((((...), False, True), False, True), dtype('int32'), None), 0, 0), 0, 0)

# or

# (((...), <cell at 0x0000017018A25888: str object at 0x000001701AF998F0>,
# <cell at 0x0000017019084498: bool object at 0x00007FFB8D0EA970>,
# <cell at 0x00000170190842B8: int object at 0x00007FFB8D16A270>,
# <cell at 0x000001701927E2E8: str object at 0x0000017018989BB0>,
# <cell at 0x0000017018A3E798: bool object at 0x00007FFB8D0EA970>),
# 0, 0, -1931060898, 32763, 451341512)

# and crashes immediately afterwards if 2 <= len(dtypes) <= 19.

# process finishes with exit code 0 if data has no additional fields except f0,
# and prints 

# (((...),),)
```

Now I'm aware that similar issues have been reported in the past:

[pickling/unpickling numpy.void and numpy.record for multiprocessing](https://numpy-discussion.scipy.narkive.com/BDhB8WM4/pickling-unpickling-numpy-void-and-numpy-record-for-multiprocessing)

[Segmentation fault with numpy.void and pickle](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14834)

[Python - pickling fails for numpy.void objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1975704/5472354)

And in a quite recent and very similar case

[Segfault after loading pickled void objects](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13593)

a [fix](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/3261532917b3c3026aa9a3002d58b5915d7f315a) seems to have been introduced, however my code still causes a crash:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Now for [Python - pickling fails for numpy.void objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1975704/5472354), the accepted answer is a comment by [jottos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14555/jottos) (Dec 29 '09 at 18:42):

> so, pickling will only work with top level module functions and classes, and will not pickle class data, so if some numpy class code/data are required to produce a representation of the numpy void type pickling isn't going to work as expected. It may be that the numpy package has implemented an internal repr to print the void type as a tuple, if this is the case then what you pickled certainly is not going to be what you printed.

But this is from over ten years ago, and it seems that bug fixes have been introduced since then. So is that still what is going on here, or is it something else? Especially since my code displays such arbitrary behavior.

### Setup Info

**Windows**: 10 Home, v. 21H1, build 19043.1288

**PyCharm**: 2021.2 (Professional), build #PY-212.4746.96

**Python** (via anaconda): 3.7.7 [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

**Numpy**: 1.19.2

**Pickle**: 4.0

Comment: I don't know if it applies to this issue or not, but there is a close association between `pickle` and `np.save`.  `save` is the `pickle` tool for numpy arrays, and if an array contains objects ('O' dtype), it uses `pickle` to write those.  So you could easily end up with several levels of 'save/pickle'.

Comment: That's interesting! Sounds plausible.

Comment: I'm having trouble to grok the MRE. Are the comments just further info for the question, some instructions I don't get, or noise? The output is consistently ``(None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`` for me, and wiggling on the size of ``dtype`` has no effect either.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi OK that is weird. For me that is really the output when I change the size of `dtype` and the code as is definitely crashes.

Comment: It could be version dependent. I've tried it with numpy 1.21.2, Python 3.9.7, MacOS 10.14.6.

Comment: Can you confirm that you see the issue with 1. newest numpy release and 2. numpy main branch (if you're comfortable with compiling it from source)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I just added info about the version where the error occurs. Now I updated `numpy` to version 1.21.2 and the code runs fine. So thanks for the tip and sorry about not checking the obvious. I was quite certain I was running the latest build. Unfortunately I don't know how to compile numpy from the source, but I guess it's not neccessary anymore.

Comment: Indeed, that last suggestion was only as a safeguard, for the off-chance that the last stable release was still buggy. (I once spent an  hour or two tracking down a bug in sympy, only to realise that it was fixed two weeks earlier in the master branch.)

Comment: @AndrasDeak If someone would like to formulate and answer feel free to go ahead. Otherwise the bounty will go to waste.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi same goes to you!

Comment: I have no idea what's going on and I'm not a windows user :) Now that we know that the problem was fixed, interested parties can start looking at PRs like https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/14940 and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/17833.